# /opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 318: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: apache-kafka, java-home

When I start Kafka on my machine this error appeared.

```
giangnt@node2:/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

[1]+  Exit 127                nohup ./kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/config/server.properties
giangnt@node2:/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin$ ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper master:2181,node1:2181,node2:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic meetuprsvptopic
/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 318: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /bin/java: No such file or directory
giangnt@node2:/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin$
```

My Kafka cluster has 3 servers. I can start one server, but 2 other brokers can't start and got error:

```
[1]+  Exit 127                nohup ./kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/config/server.properties
```

When I try to create topic in other server, I got this error,

My directory of JAVA_HOME has an space, is it the cause??:

```
/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.6.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 318: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The executable path should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`, so yes, the spacing is the issue.

I suggest you use configuration management tools to keep your cluster settings consistent

Also, systemctl or other proess management rather than nohup